# sqlite preparedstatement finalized

Tags: java, sqlite

I have an error of
java.sql.SQLException: The prepared statement has been finalized
which happens when I call the same preparedStatement a second time. I am calling it in a method.

Here is the database Java class (the relevant piece)

```
//create the charge table. (ps is PreparedStatement)
try{
   statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE charge(username TEXT NOT NULL, date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, charge REAL, PRIMARY KEY(username, date));");
} catch (SQLException ex) {
   System.out.println("charge table creation failed. exception" + ex);
}
```

Method that creates a charge:

```
 public void createCharge(String username, double amount){
    try {
        System.out.println(username + amount);

        ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO charge VALUES(?, ?, ?);");
        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setDate(2, DateConvert.toSQLDate(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.MIN)));
        ps.setDouble(3, amount);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.clearParameters();

        System.out.println("Complete");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MontsRentalDatabase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

This is in the class where the charge is created:

```
public void createCharge(String username, double amount){
    try {
        System.out.println(username + amount);

        ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO charge VALUES(?, ?, ?);");
        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setDate(2, DateConvert.toSQLDate(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.MIN)));
        ps.setDouble(3, amount);
        ps.executeUpdate(); //Line 170
        ps.clearParameters();

        System.out.println("Complete");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MontsRentalDatabase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The class that converts a normal date to sqldate:
    public class DateConvert {

```
public static java.sql.Date toSQLDate(java.util.Date date){
    return new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
}

public static java.util.Date toJavaDate(java.sql.Date date){
    return new java.util.Date(date.getTime());
}
}
```

The error is in line 170 of create charge, which is when ps.executeUpdate runs. It runs successful the first time, fails on the second.
Log:

```
450100.0
Complete
450150.0
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: The prepared statement has been finalized
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.throwex(NativeDB.java:429)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.reset(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.executeUpdate(DB.java:878)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:99)
at server.RentalDatabase.createCharge(RentalDatabase.java:170)
```

Thanks for any help,
J

Comment: It would help if you've shown all your code, not just the parts you assume are relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I am going to upload, just need to get home for a stable data connection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that this is a bug in version 3.14.2.1 of the SQLite JDBC driver.

It seems to me that you're getting a unique constraint violation exception, but the SQLite JDBC driver is tripping over itself attempting to report this exception and some other exception is getting thrown instead.

I was able to reproduce your exception using sqlite-jdbc version 3.14.2.1 if I tried to insert the same data multiple times, e.g. by re-running your code.  I downgraded the SQLite JDBC driver to 3.8.11.2 and I got the following exception after running your code:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (UNIQUE constraint failed: charge.username, charge.date)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:890)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:901)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.execute(DB.java:810)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.executeUpdate(DB.java:847)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:86)
    at com.example.MontsRentalDatabase.createCharge(MontsRentalDatabase.java:40)
    at com.example.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Of course, when re-running the program, the data I'm trying to insert is in the table already. So a unique constraint violation is to be expected.

I then added the line

```
        statement.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS charge");
```

to `createChargeTable()`, above the line that creates the table.  The code then ran successfully multiple times using either version of the SQLite JDBC driver.

This bug has now been fixed in sqlite-jdbc version 3.15.1, so the fix is therefore to upgrade to this version or later.

Comment: Possibly related issue in sqlite-jdbc's issue tracker: https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/74

Comment: Thank you Luke, I am going to try downgrading the driver, will get back to you in a couple of hours.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's due to creating two charges that have the same primary key, going to change it. (Can see it once I downgraded the Sqlite-jdbc to your version).

Comment: [link](http://www3.zippyshare.com/v/FGJnwgPf/file.html)
Would you mind taking a quick look?

I am having an issue with the creating of objects to add to the arrayList in the database search functions. The main example: public ArrayList<Rental> allRentals(){rental.add(new Rental(rent_id, username, movie_id, DateConvert.toJavaDate(withdrawn), DateConvert.toJavaDate(returned)));}

It just hangs when it has to add the object to the arrayList, it gets all the rest of the values fine from the resultSet. It's the last thing that's gotta be done, I've been stuck at this for over 8 hours. :(

Comment: For the benefit of anyone reading this comment thread, the follow-up question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192231).

Comment: It seems like it's also throws when you insert a `null` object into a column that has been defined as `NON NULL`

Answer (score -1):

After you create a prepared statement, you should close it and not use it again. I don't see it in your code, but you stated: "which happens when I call the same preparedStatement a second time".
Your 'ps' variable should be a local variable, declared in a try-with-resource block such as:

```
  try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO charge VALUES(?, ?, ?);")) {
        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setDate(2, DateConvert.toSQLDate(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.MIN)));
        ps.setDouble(3, amount);
        ps.executeUpdate(); //Line 170
        ps.clearParameters();
        System.out.println("Complete");
  }
```

That way it can't be used after its been closed.

Comment: Down vote: "After you create a prepared statement, you should close it and not use it again." . It is wrong. From PreparedStatement JavaDoc: "This object can then be used to efficiently execute this statement multiple times."

Comment: I totally agree that they can (and should) be used as you suggest, but in his code, he is recreating them each time, so he's not taking advantage of that. As such, he'd be better off using local variables, and I think it would solve his problem.

Comment: Probably It will make the code works. But it is not the point. He is trying to understand what is wrong with his code. And you didn't say it.

Comment: Thanks paul, I have changed it so that each one is now a local variable to take advantage of it. Previously I was using statement.executeUpdate() or query, but changed it not due ot the speed but due to strings that I input have '. I am going to try Luke's answer in the morning, hopefully it's something as easy as just downgrading the sqlite driver.

Comment: "After you create a prepared statement, you should close it and not use it again."